# How to tidily create multiple columns from sets of columns?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm looking to use a non-across function from mutate to create multiple columns. My problem is that the variable in the function will change along with the crossed variables. Here's an example:

```
needs=c('Sepal.Length','Petal.Length')
iris %>% mutate_at(needs, ~./'{col}.Width')
```

This obviously doesn't work, but I'm looking to divide Sepal.Length by Sepal.Width and Petal.Length by Petal.Width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `needs` should be something which is common in both the columns.

You can select the columns based on the pattern in `needs` and divide the data based on position. `!!` and `:=` is used to assign name of the new columns.

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

needs = c('Sepal','Petal')

purrr::map_dfc(needs, ~iris %>% 
                        select(matches(.x)) %>%
                        transmute(!!paste0(.x, '_divide') := .[[1]]/.[[2]]))

#    Sepal_divide Petal_divide
#1    1.457142857  7.000000000
#2    1.633333333  7.000000000
#3    1.468750000  6.500000000
#4    1.483870968  7.500000000
#...
#...
```

If you want to add these as new columns you can do `bind_cols` the above with `iris`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R approach based that the columns you want to divide have a similar name pattern,

```
res <- sapply(split.default(iris[-ncol(iris)], sub('\\..*', '', names(iris[-ncol(iris)]))), function(i) i[1] / i[2])
iris[names(res)] <- res
head(iris)

#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species Petal.Petal.Length Sepal.Sepal.Length
#1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa               7.00           1.457143
#2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa               7.00           1.633333
#3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa               6.50           1.468750
#4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa               7.50           1.483871
#5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa               7.00           1.388889
#6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa               4.25           1.384615
```